# Missing Index - Non-clustered index from Execution Plan SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

[image]

As you can see I have a three-field foreign key on my `tblClaims` table.  The `id` of this table is a sequential integer.  When running a particular query I noticed that the query too far too long to run.  So I included the execution plan and was told that

`missing index: create nonclustered index on patientid, admissiondate, dischargedate`

I'm tempted to do

```
create nonclustered index ix_tblClaims on tblClaims
(patientID asc, admissiondate asc, dischargedate asc)
```

I've read some stuff here and there about multi-column indexes or indexing each column differently.  Is it correct that only one index will be used if I follow the indexing each column separately method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Think of it this way, if I gave you a map which listed all towns by name, you would find the town you wanted to go to quickly. If it then had all street addresses listed in order, then you could find the '10 london road' addresses pretty quickly, but it might take you a while to find the one in the town you were looking for. If it had an index at the back where it was ordered by town, then by street, then you could find the actual address you were looking for in one step, really very quickly.

Indexing in a database is no different. If you need to look up based on more than one thing, then you need an index which can cover the things you are looking up on.

Comment: I added the index in question and a query went from 42 seconds to less than one :)